# Computing the minimum number of terms required in a Fourier series to achieve a particular upper bound on the error

Tags: fourier-analysis

In a Fourier series, the maximum error bound is the difference of the function and the partial sum of its Fourier series. Within an interval, as we increase the number of terms of partial sums, the error decreases.

$$e(x) = \left|f(x) − s(x)\right|$$

How can I determine the number of terms needed to calculate the partial sum so as to have a specific maximum error bound? For e.g $|e(x)| ≤ 0.01$ or $|e(x)| ≤ 0.001$

For example in a typical question, $f(x)$ defined as

$$f (x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 &−3 \leq x \leq 0\\
x^2(3 − x) & 0 < x < 3
\end{cases}$$

is a periodic function with period $6$ i.e., $f (x + 6) = f (x)$

- Plot $|e(x)|$ versus $x$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 3$ for several values of $m$.
- Find the smallest value of $m$ for which $|e(x)| ≤ 0.1$ for all $x$.

Constructing the Fourier series for this periodic function and plotting $|e(x)|$ versus $x$ for several partial sums like $m = 5, 10, 20$ is easy. It can be accomplished by `DiscretePlot`.

How can I find the smallest value of $m$ (i.e., the number of terms needed in the partial sum to achieve a specific error bound)?

I use Mathematica 6 and 7.

Comment: I think this is more a math question than a *Mathematica* one...

Comment: @J.M. likely, but I wonder if a programmatic solution could be devised.

Comment: Suppose i have to calculate m, that is number of terms needed for partial sum so as to obtain error bound of very small order. Like 0.00001.  Then i have to calculate partial sum to a high degree. maybe to m = 100.

Comment: I smell a homework question...

Comment: In the interest of teaching you how to fish: try `FourierTrigSeries[UnitStep[x] (3 - x) x^2, x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/3}]`, where `n` is the number of terms you need for the Fourier series.

Comment: I already know how to make Fourier series on mathematica.

Comment: Right, so make plots of the difference between the function and the Fourier series, for an increasing number of terms. Note the numbers in the vertical axis.

Comment: You mean i should use Discreteplot of error function with value range of m. Problem is that if i have to examine small error bound say 0.000001. Then m goes to many terms and its plot looks like a continuous curve. Suppose i make Discreteplot for m = 200 terms. Then i can't tell where the error bound is achieved because plot looks continuous.

Comment: That's what the option `PlotRange` is for. You do need to exert some effort here; *Mathematica* won't do everything for you.

Comment: PlotRange is a simple way which i have to use. I wanted a more robust approach to the problem. Perhaps i have to wait until i move on to Numerical analysis and become more proficient with Mathematica.

Comment: Are you sure it is the max error you want to bound, as opposed to RMS (that is, L^2) error? The Gibbs phenomenon will keep the former bounded away from zero in general. (Maybe that was the point of the exercise??)

Comment: @J.M. Interesting... I did not know `cases` was supported. Will certainly be helpful

Comment: @R.M: yes, it's on [the list](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If function $f$ has period $2b$ and is defined on $(-b,b)$ then

```
b = 3;
f [x_] := x^2 (3 - x) Boole[0 < x < b]
Clear[g]
g[n_, x_] := g[n, x] = FourierTrigSeries[f[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, \[Pi]/b}] // 
   FullSimplify
maxdif[n_] := NMaximize[{Abs[f[x] - g[n, x]], {-b <= x < b}}, x][[1]]
```

gives function `maxdif` calculating the maximum of the absolute value between $f$ and the $n$-th partial Fourier sum. From here it is straightforward to write code calculating the required minimal value of $n$.

Comment: There's a `FourierTrigSeries[]` function which would be more appropriate here, I think...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, changed it.

Comment: Thanks. But i still don't understand how to calculate n for desired error bound.

Comment: @kevin If we have a function depending on $n$ the simplest way is to write a cycle, which would check `maxdif[n]` until the required value will be found. Or one can try `maxdif[2^m]`, $m=1,2,\ldots$ until getting the bound and then using bisection method.

Comment: The problem is that i am not proficient with Numerical analysis package of Mathematica because its not part of my course yet.Though i understood the basic idea you stated. I do not understand how to apply it in Mathematica.

Comment: @kevin There is no numerical stuff involved, it's just checking in a cycle say if `maxdif[1]<10^-4`, then if `maxdif[2]<10^-4` etc.

Comment: @Andrew. Ok i will give it a try.

Comment: Well i get the idea. But my PC is taking a long time when working on smaller and smaller bounds. Maybe because it goes to lengthy calculations as partial sum of Fourier series gets expanded.

Comment: @kevin For large $n$ deleting `//FullSimplify` which is not necessary for `FourierTrigSeries` could improve timing a bit.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this is not possible (though it is with your example function).  Fourier series minimize error with respect to the mean squared error ($L_2$ norm), which is not the same as the max absolute error that you want ($L_\infty$ norm).  The mean squared error goes to zero in the limit, but the max error may not -- any function with a step discontinuity will *always* have a non-zero max error in its Fourier series near the discontinuity ([Gibbs phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon)), no matter how many terms you take.  So for a large class of functions, your error criterion is effectively useless.  Since your function doesn't have such discontinuities, I think the max error will eventually go to zero, but I'm not certain.

Fortunately, if you change your error criterion to the mean squared error, you can use a simple formula to find it exactly using only the Fourier coefficients.

$$e^2 = \int_{-b}^b |f(x)|^2 dx - \sum_{n=-N}^N |\phi_n|^2 |F[n]|^2$$

where $F[n]$ is a Fourier coefficient, and the $\phi_k$ depends on the particular definition of Fourier series that you're using (which you didn't specify).  This comes directly from [Bessel's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_inequality).